# Excel VBA find all values in row and save different column values to variables

Tags: vba, excel

I've done quite a bit of searching and can't find any code that matches my situation or to a point I can modify except for one.

Looking at the spreadsheet below.  I want to have the user enter the `OrderNumber` then search `Column A` for every value of that number.  As it does I want it to copy the `ItemNumber` and `QtyOrdered` to two different variables in order to put them into textboxes later on.

I want it to "stack" the information into the variable so something like `ItemNumValues = ItemNumValues + Cell.Value`

[image: Spreadsheet]

I tried to modify code from someone else ("their code") but I am getting a mismatch type error.  The rest of the code works.  There are some trace elements in the script from previous features that aren't used and I just haven't removed them yet.

```
'***********************************************************
'********** Their Code Follows *****************
'***********************************************************

    Dim numentries As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    '***********************************************************

    'Get number of entries
    numentries = Worksheets(Sheet1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
    '*************************************************************

    'Run loop to cycle through all entries (rows) to copy
    For i = 1 To numentries

         If (Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 2, 1).Value = InStr(1, Cell, OrderNumber, vbTextCompare)) Then
              MsgBox Test
        End If

    Next i

End If   

'***********************************************************
'********** End Their Code *****************
'***********************************************************
```

Comment: What line does the error occur on?

Comment: `While Len(OrderNumber) < 6 Or Len(OrderNumber) > 6`... VBA has the `<>` operator....

Comment: Very difficult to track your code. Either post a more complete problem description or, better, try to minimize it so we can better understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: `numentries = Worksheets(Sheet1).UsedRange.Rows.Count` is wrong. It should be `numentries = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count`

Comment: Also, what is `Cell`? `= InStr(1, Cell, OrderNumber, vbTextCompare)) Then ...`

Comment: @BruceWayne copy/pasted it from somewhere.  I probably need to remove `Cell` from that.

Comment: @A.S.H minimized it just to the code I'm looking to improve upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a multidimensional array. If you've never used arrays before, I strongly suggest reading up on them.

```
Sub GatherData()
Dim c As Range
Dim aGetData() As Variant 'This is our array
Dim i As Integer
Dim a As Integer
Dim iRowCount As Integer
Dim sRange As String

'Gather data
iRowCount = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
For Each c In Range("A2:A" & iRowCount)
  If c.Value = 636779 Then
    ReDim Preserve aGetData(2, i) 'An array must have a set size but as we
    'do not know how many order numbers will be found we have to 'resize'
    'the array to account for how many we do find. Using "ReDim Preserve" 
    'keeps any data we have placed into the array while at the same time
    'changing it's size.
    For a = 0 To 2 'Our first index will hold each col of data that is why
                   'it is set to 2 (arrays start at a base of zero, so
                   '0,1,2 will be each col(A,B,C)
      aGetData(a, i) = c.Offset(0, a) 'This gets each value from col A,B and C
    Next a
    i = i + 1 'Increment for array in case we find another order number
              'Our second index "aGetData(index1,index2) is being resized 
              'this represents each order number found on the sheet
  End If
Next c

'How to read the array
For i = 0 To UBound(aGetData())
  For a = 0 To 2
    Debug.Print aGetData(a, i)
  Next a
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `OrderNumber` (column `A`) is sorted. Very good news (if they're not, just sort them ;) ). This simple function will get you the `ItemNumber`s and `QtyOrdered` into a bi-dimensional array, where each row is a pair of them.

```
Function ArrItemQty(ByVal OrderNumber As Long)
With Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Offset(1)
        .AutoFilter 1, OrderNumber
        ArrItemQty= .Resize(, 2).Offset(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).value
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Function
```

And here's a little testing:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, ar
    ar = ArrItemQty(636779)
    For i = LBound(ar, 1) To UBound(ar, 1)
         Debug.Print
         For j = LBound(ar, 2) To UBound(ar, 2): Debug.Print ar(i, j),: Next
     Next
End Sub
```

p.s. be aware that the resulting array is 1-based. Use `LBound` and `UBound` as indicated is safest.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I had already started working on adapting Craig's answer and got it working so I didn't attempt yours.

Comment: @Travis You are welcome. Be aware however that `ReDim`ing an array as it grows element by element is something to avoid wherever possible; as it can get very slow for large data.